# Get CSS from different domain blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: css, scripting, cross-domain

I have a RestApi with some scripts contents CSS etc. When I try to add a CSS from the API with the URL link I'm getting blocked by CORS policy:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

This only happens when I try to get a CSS which references to a `.wolf` or `.ttf`. like `fontasome` or `flaticon`

My third-party-site-api already supports cores, I'm able to get scripts and content, and make post and get by AJAX even working with signalr (websockets).

I have seen that you need to add: `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` and `config.EnableCors()`;
but I'm just trying to access to a file, not a controller so I don't know where else have to add it.

This is how I want to get the CSS

```html
<link href="https://myapi/assets/ccs/flaticon.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This is the error:

> Access to Font at `https://myapi/assets/ccs/flaticon.woff` from origin `https://ahotherapp` has been blocked by CORS policy: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First please read this [Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) to know how you can share resources with CORS.

> The CORS standard works by adding new HTTP headers which allow servers to serve resources to permitted origin domains. Browsers support these headers and respect the restrictions they establish.

**Example**: Say your site is http://my-cool-site.com and, you have a third party API at domain http://third-party-site.com, which you can access via AJAX.

And let's assume that a page you server from my-cool-site.com made a request to third-party-site.com. Normally, users browser will decline AJAX calls to any other site other than your own domain/subdomain per the [Same-Origin Security Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). But if the browser and the third party server supports CORS, the following things happen:

- Browser will send the following HTTP header to third-party-site.com

  ```
  Origin: http://my-cool-site.com
  ```
- If the third party server accepts requests from your domain, it will respond with the following HTTP header:

  ```
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://my-cool-site.com
  ```
- To allow all domains, third party server can send this header:

  ```
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  ```
- If your site is not allowed, browser will throw an error.

If the client's have fairly modern [browsers that support CORS](http://caniuse.com/cors), and your third party server [supports CORS](http://client.cors-api.appspot.com/client) as well, you can definitely go for it with minor changes to your code.

---

Comment: My third-party-site allready supports cores, I'm able to get scripts and content, and make post and get by AJAX even working with signalr (websockets). in this Case I'm not using AJAX is just the link reference to a font, when my reference script have a .woff file or .ttf doesnt work. I'm not even accessing to the api just a css file.

Comment: @Alejandro Gomez Guerrero, I saw your Edit. It's about your specific CSS URL and not related to the other like fonts, WebSocket,... There is nothing more in the CORS. please check the header response in the `developer tools` and make sure the right header of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is present.

Comment: I can get this: <link href="https://myapi/assets/ccs/boostrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> this not: <link href="https://myapi/assets/ccs/flaticon.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> same directory boostrap doesnt have .wolf or .ttf file but flaticon does and that one is the bocked how can i fix it

Comment: He's asking how to access a css file, and you've told him how to add code to an HTML page. Just seen my console clobbered with about 50 cookies with "attribute value “Lax” or “Strict” was omitted because of a cross-site redirect" ... and I'm not even a single cookie in my CSS / HTML code ! (Closer investigation shows it's something to do with a site called "hubspot" ... even though they're nothing to do with my code !)

Answer (score 1):

put you css at https domain, insiden a php file and add this headers

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: text/css');
?>
.justificado {
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: inter-word;
}
.centrado {
    text-align: center;
}
```

And include with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://domain/custom_css.php"  crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```